# How to find a research supervisors and a research team?

Tags: computer-science, independent-researcher, research-proposal, motivation

I am finishing my master’s degree in computer science this year. After my first year I understood that I have a big passion for research in the field of AI and cognition. However, the research questions that I have are strange. I am trying to understand memory and implement its abstract mechanisms (more similar to Neural Turing Machine, than RNNs and LSTMs). However, I can’t find people who have an interest in this field. I am fearful that I’d have to resort to other topics that I am not really interested about, and pretend that I enjoy it. Moreover, I am required to conduct research during my last semester and present the work that I’ve done.

Answer (score -1):

Reach out and talk to the faculties and propose your project. They may not have listed every single idea they are interested in on their page. And most faculties are more open to master projects since that's basically free...